# Javascript Form Validation - Textbox Check

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, textbox

I'm trying to validate the form to see if the textbooks are filled.
It is supposed to alert whether or not the boxes are filled after you submit, but my page isn't doing anything. I'm not sure what could be going wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#customerSubmit').click(function(e) {
          var isValid = true;
          $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
             if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                 isValid = false;
                 $(this).css({
                     "border": "1px solid red",
                     "background": "#FFCECE"
                 });
             } else {
                 $(this).css({
                     "border": "",
                     "background": ""
             });
           }
       });
       if (isValid == false) {
           e.preventDefault();
       } else { 
           alert('Thank you for submitting');
    });
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
    <h3>Contact Information </h3>
        <table class="customerInfo">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="custFirstName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Last Name:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="custLastName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <div class="control-group" id="controlEmail">
                <tr>
                    <th>Email:</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="custEmail" id="email"/></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
        <input id="customerSubmit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="customerSubmit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error you seeing on console?

Comment: There is formatting issue in your code. Fixed it here : http://jsfiddle.net/x74h9nfd/

Comment: You aware your code as syntax error?!

Comment: you are not closing one of your else {}  hint "Thank you for Submitting"

Answer (score 0):

your missing an end bracket on your `else` at the very bottom of your code.